# (Android/Java) Editing EditText's default text?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Sorry for my bad English, I speak French. To better understand my problem, you might need to know this:

"nom" means "name"
"modifier" means "edit"
"jeux" means "games"
"jeuxValide" means "valid games"
"positionJeuchoisis" means "chosen game's position"
"rechercher" means "to search"
"ListeJeux" means "game list"

Enough for the French teaching, here is my problem (I know its not very clear..)

I have an EditText with default text in it (a "nom" (name) the user entered a while back).
I want the user to be able to edit the text in the editText, without him rewriting everything in it. I want the user to be able to simply edit the EditText's text.

This is the method that return what is inside the editText (it should...):

```
private String setupNom() {
    EditText editNom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomModifier);
    editNom.setText(RechercherActivity.jeuxValides.get(ListeActivity.positionJeuChoisis).getNom());     
    String nom = editNom.getText().toString();
    return nom + "";
}
```

This is the "modifier" button, which set an object's parameter to the text inside the editText at the end of the activity.

```
private void setupModifierButton() {
    Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAjouterAjouterModifier);

    retourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ListeJeux.jeux.size(); i++) {
                if ((ListeJeux.jeux.get(i).getNom())
                        .equals(RechercherActivity.jeuxValides.get(ListeActivity.positionJeuChoisis).getNom())) {
                    ListeJeux.jeux.get(i).setNom(setupNom());
                }
            }

            ListeJeux.saveListe(ModifierActivity.this);

            Log.i("Modifier", "Jeu modifié avec succès");
            Toast.makeText(ModifierActivity.this, "Jeu modifié avec succès!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            startActivity(new Intent(ModifierActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

I want the editText to show the "nom" entered by the user a while back.
But then, I want the user to be able to edit it.
Then when I press the "modifier" button, I want this:
ListeJeux.jeux.get(i).setNom(What is inside the editText at the end)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Where is the code for *clicking on "continue"*?

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated my post.

Comment: So you are starting a new activity, but when you go back you want to keep the value you entered? Just curious, are these `static` variables `RechercherActivity.jeuxValides` and `ListeJeux.jeux`? Because static variables are not how you share information across activities.

Comment: I have an arraylist (jeuxListe) full of games (jeux). Those jeux are hardcoded into the app. I have a class that allow the user to search for jeux that fit his criterias. I put those into a temporary arraylist (jeuxValide). Once the user click on a game in the jeuxValides list, I want him to be able to change the name of the jeux. For that, I have a "for" that search my original list (jeuxListe) for the item that is the same as the one the user clicked on, then use "setNom" to change the name of this jeux to the one inside the editText.

Comment: Okay. Do you have the code for the item click listener on the list? And you shouldn't need to search the list if you can just get the juex object directly from the adapter

Comment: @cricket_007 The code is already there I think. The way I'm using the editText, it shows the default name, but I want to be able to change it.

Comment: I don't see that code anywhere in your post. I'm having problems following the full path of your code between the MainActivity, ModifierActivity, ListeActivity, ListeJeux, and RechercherActivity classes... :\

Comment: Well, I can give you all the 10 classes I have, but you might have difficulties finding the code you are looking for in it, do you want me to copy/paste all the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99557/discussion-between-cricket-007-and-trexiic).